# How to get value in radio input in post meta box?

Tags: posts, metabox

I use this code when create input box for post meta box:

```
<input type="text" name="<?php echo $name; ?>" id="x" value="<?php echo $value; ?>" />
```

Now I need to handle radio box which has 2 inputs with the same name:

```
<input type="radio" name="option" id="option-current" value="0" />
<input type="radio" name="option" id="option-custom" value="1" />
```

If use  echo $name; and echo $value  with radio type, post meta will have 2 value for one key, that makes the radio selection lost meaning.

How to get correct result from the radio type?

Answer (score 1):

Radio buttons should have the same name with different values if you want to group them together. I'd call them something that isn't option and not use the ID.

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp